# Figuring out what a MIP code does

Tags: assembly, mips, microprocessors

I've been asked to find out what the following MIPs code does, unfortunately I'm kinda lost. So, can anyone help me out with this code.

```
.data 
str1: .asciiz   " My favorite number is" 

str2:   .asciiz     ".\n My least favorite number is " 
.text
addi    $a0, $0, 0
addi    $v0, $0, 4
syscall     
addi    $a0, $0, 42     
addi    $v0, $0, 1
syscall         
la  $a0, str2 
syscall     
li  $v0, 4      
syscall     
li  $a0, 21 
li  $v0, 1      
syscall         
li $v0, 10 
syscall
```

Comment: You could've just ran it in a MIPS simulator like SPIM or MARS.

Answer (score 0):

What that code does depends *entirely* on what the `syscall` calls are doing, since that's not actually part of the MIPS ISA.

My (relatively educated) guess (based on the execution flow, strings and the way system calls tend to work) is that it would be printing out the favourite and least-favourite numbers, `42` and `21`:

```
.data 
str1: .asciiz   " My favorite number is" 

str2:   .asciiz     ".\n My least favorite number is " 

.text

addi    $a0, $0, 0    ; add zero register and 0, giving $a0 (str1)
addi    $v0, $0, 4    ; $v0 = 4 means print string at $a0
syscall               ; print string

addi    $a0, $0, 42   ; favourite number = 42 (RIP, Douglas Adams).
addi    $v0, $0, 1    ; $v0 = 1 means print integer in $a0
syscall               ; print 42

la  $a0, str2         ; string for least-favourite.
syscall               ; probably shouldn't be here, it's going to
                      ;   print the address of str2 as an integer.
li  $v0, 4            ; $v0 = 4 means print string.
syscall     

li  $a0, 21           ; least favourite is 21
li  $v0, 1      
syscall               ; print it

li $v0, 10 
syscall               ; halt/stop/exit or something.
```